# angular2 and material design autocomplete, dropdown with opt group

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I am using Angular2 and angular material design ("@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1") and I am trying to implement this functionality of autocomplete with dropdown that contains select options and optgroups.

I have a group of countries + cities in each of the country so:

SERBIA

- Belgrade
- Novi Sad

SWEDEN

- Stockholm

....

Any suggestions?